# How to clear setTimer in another function

Tags: react-native

A component is calling a function in another file, a setTimer is use to update a variable:

timer.js

```
const timer = () => {
  this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    pressTwice = false;
  }, duration);
};
```

timerUI.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    timer();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);// how to clean the this.timeout?
  }
```

I am getting this error:

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmouted component.
```

Comment: Data (i.e. state & props) generally flow "down" the react component tree, i.e. parent to child. The solution if a child's sibling needs access to data at or below its level is to "loft" the data to the closest common ancestor, the parent in this case. In other words, you need track the timers in the parent so a different child component can receive a ref to it via props to cancel it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data (i.e. state & props) generally flow "down" the react component tree, i.e. parent to child. The solution if a child's sibling needs access to data at or below its level is to "loft" the data to the closest common ancestor, the parent in this case. In other words, you need track the timers in the parent so a different child component can receive a ref to it via props to cancel it.

Hopefully this illustrates it concept:

parent

```
const setTimer = () => {
  this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  pressTwice = false;
}, duration);

render() {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildSetsTimer setTimer={this.setTimer} />
      <ChildClearsTimer timerRef={this.timeout} />
    </>
  );
}
```